# Which way is the best to take a json with a huge number of elements and manipulate them?

Tags: java, android, json, mobile-development

I have a URL which point to a JSON with 6400 elements; I have to take those elements and show them on a Map by creating markers.
Since this JSON is quite big I'm wondering which is the best way to manipulate its elements and which is the best way to separate code for a low coupling and high cohesion. I was thinking about using a JSON Library to save all the elements inside an ArrayList and when the map opens, I'll take elements from the ArrayList to create markers. I think that my solution may be expensive and maybe the app will need a lot of time to manipulate all those data. Any suggestion?

Comment: 6400 is not "huge", assuming the data in each element is fairly small. You will probably have more trouble with the performance (and readability!) of a map with that many markers on it, than with the actual processing of the data. Consider using some kind of clustering algorithm (there are libraries for that).

Comment: Also using an `Array` instead of `ArrayList` will be better for performance, but for this you have to know exact number of elements.

Comment: If you don't need to have all the data de-serialized to memory, use event/stream oriented parsing with streaming IO instead of object mapping. For example, read chunk of data with a buffer from Socket's InputStream, push the chunk to a parser like https://github.com/anatolygudkov/green-jelly, process notifications in your listener, read a buffer from Socket again... Just for example, if you need to store JSON objects to a DB: setAutoCommit(false) on JSON started, send/add to a batch a JDBC insert on each object finished, commit() on JSON end... This is like DOM vs SAX/StAX, btw

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean [Pagination](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging)? In such case you must use [PagedListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/PagedListAdapter), a suitable codelabs tutorial can be found [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-paging/#0).

Comment: No, i didn't.. or at least I don't know if it's a good idea to consider pagination for my purpose (related to Google Maps markers)!